# sql repeated date rows to columns on a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, rows

I'm looking for something similar to the pivot function
I have a table that shows date ranges for users, something that tells me that the user was absent between some period of time.

| Id | UserId | BeginingTime | EndTime | DateApplied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 01-01-2017 |
| 2 | 63 | 10:00 | 10:40 | 01-01-2017 |
| 3 | 63 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 03-01-2017 |
| 4 | 63 | 14:30 | 15:30 | 04-01-2017 |
| 5 | 63 | 13:00 | 13:30 | 03-01-2017 |

I know for a fact that I can only have 2 permissions per day, I need to group the ones that have the same date into a new table.

Data should look something like this

| UserId | ID1 | BeginTime1 | EndTime1 | ID2 | BeginTime2 | EndTime2 | DateApplied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | 1 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 2 | 10:00 | 10:40 | 01-01-2017 |
| 63 | 3 | 11:00 | 12:00 | 5 | 13:00 | 13:30 | 03-01-2017 |
| 63 | 4 | 14:30 | 15:30 | null | null | null | 04-01-2017 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know you are going to group at most 2 records per user per day, you can simply use a CTE and a left join:

```
;WITH p AS (
  SELECT Id, UserId, BeginingTime, EndTime, DateApplied, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, DateApplied ORDER BY BeginingTime) AS RowNo
  FROM SourceTable
)
SELECT p1.UserId, p1.Id as ID1, 
       p1.BeginingTime AS BeginingTime1, p1.EndTime AS EndTime1,
       p2.Id as ID2, 
       p2.BeginingTime AS BeginingTime2, p2.EndTime AS EndTime2,
       p1.DateApplied
FROM p p1 LEFT JOIN p p2 
          ON p1.UserId = p2.UserId AND p1.DateApplied = p2.DateApplied AND p2.RowNo = 2
WHERE p1.RowNo = 1
```